# Asterisk : Getting Yellow alarm

Tags: asterisk

Actually we have two digium card in our machine  , one is two port card another one is four port card . And we have installed zaptel and asterisk in that machine.  we are getting yellow alarm in 2nd and 4th port in second card ,rest of ports are getting the green alarm. What could be reason for this problem ..

Please, Any one can help me out of this problem.......

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.asteriskguru.com/tutorials/yellow_alarm.html, perhaps?